# SAP WS_DOWNLOAD function module non-english language conversion

Tags: excel, download, abap, codepages, non-english

So, I am trying to develop a Z_PROGRAM which extracts some specific data from basic SAP FI database tables such as BKPF and BSEG. I am using a function module called 'WS_DOWNLOAD', which is obsolete, though the same issue persists when I use the newer version 'GUI_DOWNLOAD', too (the reason I'm using the obsolete version is because the specified SAP version of my client is very old and set to be upgraded in 2022, therefore 'GUI_DOWNLOAD' doesn't exist). The issue concerns any data that is in a non-english language, with the one I specifically need being greek, which in the created file shows up as '######'. The file I'm creating is in .xls format and the code I'm using is as follows:

```
call function 'WS_DOWNLOAD'
        exporting
         filename                      = 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test_folder\bkpf.xls'
         filetype                      = 'DAT'
         codepage                      = 'XXXX'
        tables
         data_tab                      = it_bkpf
        exceptions
         file_open_error               = 1
         file_write_error              = 2
         invalid_filesize              = 3
         invalid_type                  = 4
         no_batch                      = 5
         unknown_error                 = 6
         invalid_table_width           = 7
         gui_refuse_filetransfer       = 8
         customer_error                = 9
         no_authority                  = 10
         others                        = 11.
```

Now, in other systems where that problem has occured, I've solved it by adjusting the 'codepage' parameter. However, I cannot seem to find the right codepage here so I wanted to ask if you guys know any other reason why this is happening or maybe suggest another solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The file you create might be named .xls, but it's not actually an excel workbook. One does not simply create excel workbooks in ABAP. Not without a library like ABAP2XLSX. What you get is a flatfile which Excel believes to be able to interpret. As far as I remember, Excel allows you to select a codepage when opening a file that way.

Comment: I think you can use the code page `4103` which stands for UTF-16 Little Endian, that Microsoft Office supports very well.